# Network with a router and IPS

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, freebsd

I´d like to tool around a little bit with a network using a router which is connected to a modem and a Intrusion Protection System (FreeBSD) in between the router and the other computers/servers. Without the use of wlan.

How do I set this up?

My router has the following settings

> IP 192.168.1.2 
>   wlan=OFF 
>   DHCP=ON 
>   DHCP starts at 192.168.1.10 
>   Internet=ON

IPS (freeBSD) `/etc/rc.conf` where `vr0` is my network card

> ifconfig_vr0="inet 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0" 
>   defaultrouter="192.168.1.1" 
>   Three network cards: vr0, r10 and r11 
>   Internet=ON

Another FreeBSD system. Let's call it ping101. I connected ping101 to `r10` or `r11` of my IPS not to the router with the following settings in the `/etc/rc.conf`

> ifconfig_em0="inet 192.168.1.3 netmask 255.255.255.0" 
>   defaultrouter="192.168.1.2"  (to my IPS)

With this setup I can't seem to ping my ping101 or ping the IPS/router with ping101.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So in your IPS you only have a single NIC? How are you routing traffic then?

Comment: In my IPS I have 3 NIC's: vr0, r10 and r11. Traffic should go from computers -> IPS -> router -> Modem.  The IPS is set up to use vr0 as gateway (from IPS to router). All other computers should connect to the IPS using r10 or r11.

Comment: I read now that my IPS should be configured as "bridge".

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a bridge in the IPS in this screnario.

I connected to the IPS and created a bridge

```
# ifconfig bridge create
bridge0
```

As shown above bridge0 was created.
Now connect the NIC's together. In my example `vr0` is the NIC to the router and `rl0 and rl1` are the one being connected to the Personal Computer's.

```
# ifconfig bridge0 addm rl0 up
ifconfig: BRDGADD rl0: File exists
# ifconfig bridge0 addm vr0 up
ifconfig: BRDGADD vr0: File exists
# ifconfig rl0 up
# ifconfig vr0 up
```

Check if both the rl0 and rl1 have been added to the interface: `bridge0`.

```
# ifconfig bridge0

    member: rl0 flags=143<LEARNING,DISCOVER,AUTOEDGE,AUTOPTP>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 2 priority 128 path cost 200000
    member: vr0 flags=143<LEARNING,DISCOVER,AUTOEDGE,AUTOPTP>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 1 priority 128 path cost 200000
```

Now Personal Computers can connect to the IPS (192.168.1.2). A FreeBSD server for example can add to its `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
defaultrouter="192.168.1.2"
```

Documentation for bridging in FreeBSD can be found [here](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-bridging.html) on the official webpage.